# Nondeterminstic Linear Time vs Other Complexity Classes

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, time-complexity

Is it known whether or not nondeterministic linear time contains $P$ and/or smaller classes such as Uniform-$NC^1$?

Comment: Relevant: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16385/nondeterministic-linear-time-vs-the-deterministic-time-hierarchy

Comment: @ClementC. I agree that post is related.  However, I'm interested in the opposite containment, i.e. is $P\subset NTIME(n)$ or $NC^1\subset NTIME(n)$?

Comment: Considering that [Cook](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82028132.pdf) proved $NTIME(n^r)\subsetneq NTIME(n^s)$ for $1<=r < s$, I'm assuming the containment for $P$ is not known.  However, the case $NC^1$ is rather interesting.  I suspect [Quasi-Realtime Languages](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01705890) implies $NC^1\subset NTIME(n)$.  However, I'm not sure how the reduction argument would go.

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/40801/are-there-languages-in-dtime2tn-that-are-not-in-ntimetn

Comment: @AviTal.  Thank you for the link.  Unfortunately, it doesn't quite address my question since I'm interested in polynomial time (or classes in $P$) rather than exponential time.

Comment: @AlexWilliams - One of the answers suggests that it is still open weather NTIME(n)=E, which may imply that your question is difficult...

Comment: Hi @AlexWilliams Recently, I've been wondering if $P$ could be contained in non-deterministic linear time with bounded non-determinism.  I have a few related results.  I would be happy to discuss if you're interested.  :)